# Pointers and cache utilisation

Tags: c++, c, pointers, caching, processor

I am just starting working with processors and can't understand the following.

Asume that we have an array declared as

```
static double x[1000][3]
```

that we access in a function

```
double up (double *a, int i)
{
    double t=*(a+i*3);
    return t;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    static double x[1000][3];
    //some manipulations//
    double b;
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        b=up(&x[0][0],i);
     }
}
```

In this case, what is loaded into cache memory - actual values that a pointer is pointing to or only addresses? If addresses - does it mean there will be another cycle to load actual values? Is it all-in-all good for cache utilisation with respect to this loop?

Comment: Sorry be specific on a problem or observation you have. Otherwise this question is OT as 'Too broad'!

Comment: The code posted most likely won't compile, and if it does, it would not run, since it uses 8MB of stack, which is likely going to overflow the stack...

Comment: The question is not about compilation, it's just an example. I need to know how pointers work in cache

Comment: Also, `i` is not declared, so we have no idea what you're trying to do

Comment: Anyway, the question isn't very clear, but if you mean what I think than no - a cached line is standalone, it has the address *and* the data stored locally, so you won't need to access the memory again unless it gets evicted

Comment: Question is unclear, please elaborate.

Comment: Does that mean that cache needs two times more space to store pointers and values?

Comment: Discussing a non-functional example would be pointless. What you are actually asking - as the question is posted - is "I'm told that a + b = 5? Is this true, because I thought a was 6 and b was 19". Unfortunately, the assumptions you're basing your question on seem completely flawed.

Comment: The short answer is, "it depends on the platform". Neither the C nor the C++ language specifications say anything about processor cache, so it's an implementation detail generally implemented by the CPU and compiler designers to provide the best performance on the platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact answer is platform specific, but generally speaking, three things cause data in external memory to be loaded into the processor cache.

The most obvious is an actual instruction that accesses the memory in the ordinary way. If that memory address is not resident in processor cache, the processor will have to acquire it. The second way is speculative prefetching. Some processors will acquire memory into cache if they believe the code might access it. Lastly, compilers can actually emit instructions to put things into cache.

All your operations are on pointers, so that's all they'll load, except this one: `double t=*(a+i*3);`. That actually dereferences a pointer and accesses its value. So unless the compiler is smart enough to optimize the access away (because you never use the result) that is likely the only part of your code that will result in something other than a pointer being read from main memory into cache. (Assuming it ever gets to main memory, which depends on your cache size.)

Comment: If the compiler were smart enough to optimize that dereference away, it would also be smart enough to replace this entire program with nothing... because the program functionally does nothing.